# Translation Issue with Wordpress Theme Check in comment_form function

Tags: theme-development, themes, translation, comment-form

I ended my wordpress theme, which called the_mdttheme.

I tried to check it and get two errors with translation in `comment_form()`.

Can't understand what did wrong, can someone help me? Here is two warnings:

WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function _x, with the arguments 'Comment', 'the_mdttheme'

WARNING: Found a translation function that is missing a text-domain. Function _x, with the arguments 'Comment *', 'the_mdttheme'

Here is my code, warnings are inside `'comment_field'`:

```
$args = array(
    'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label class="hidden" for="comment">' . _x( 'Comment', 'the_mdttheme' ) . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true" required="required" placeholder="' . _x( 'Comment *', 'the_mdttheme' ) . '"></textarea></p>',
    'submit_button' => '<div class="form-submit-wrapper"><input name="%1$s" type="submit" id="%2$s" class="%3$s" value="%4$s" /></div>',
    'label_submit'  => __( 'comment', 'the_mdttheme' ),
);
comment_form($args);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`_x()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_x) function is meant to be used with the same string/text which has two or more different meanings/contexts, e.g. "read" can be a verb (`I can read music.`) or noun (`It's a good read.`).

And when you use `_x()`, the context is the second parameter and the text domain is the third parameter, but in your code, you incorrectly used `_x()`, where these are missing the context:

```php
_x( 'Comment', 'the_mdttheme' )
_x( 'Comment *', 'the_mdttheme' )
```

But that would actually be seen as missing the text domain since it's supposed to be the third parameter.

So either provide the context (and also do so with your POT file) or perhaps you meant to use `__()`? :)

Comment: OMG, I forgot about $context. Thanks!!!